# Not able to add target action to a class UIButton inside a custom View class

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I am facing issue in adding target action to a UIButton created in a custom UIView class.

Please look into this code for explanation-

```swift
public class ReActivateSubscriptionView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var reActiveSubscriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var activateNowButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var collapseSubscribeViewButton: UIButton!


    var viewModel: ReActivateSubscriptionViewPresentable! {
        didSet {
            viewModel.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func configure(with viewModel: ReActivateSubscriptionViewPresentable) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        configureSubViews()
    }

    public static var isCollapsed = false

    public class var collapsedActivateNowBtn: UIButton {
        let activateButton = UIButton()

        activateButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16.0, y: 112, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32, height: 33)
        activateButton.applyStyle(Style.reActivateSubscriptionConfig.activateButton, text: Asset.String.reActivateButtonText, textAlignment: .center, shouldUnderline: true)
        activateButton.addCornerRadius(radius: 6.0)
        return activateButton
    }

    public func configureSubViews() {
        self.backgroundColor = .black
        self.reActiveSubscriptionLabel.applyStyle(Style.reActivateSubscriptionConfig.reActivateSubscribeLabel, text: Asset.String.reActivateText, textAlignment: .center)
        self.activateNowButton.applyStyle(Style.reActivateSubscriptionConfig.activateButton, text: Asset.String.reActivateButtonText, textAlignment: .center, shouldUnderline: true)
        self.addCornerRadius(radius: 6.0)
        self.collapseSubscribeViewButton.setImage(Asset.Image.whiteUpArrow, for: .normal)
        self.collapseSubscribeViewButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(collapseActivateView), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.activateNowButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(activateSubscription), for: .touchUpInside)
        ReActivateSubscriptionView.collapsedActivateNowBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(activateSubscription), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func collapseActivateView() {
        viewModel.handleCollapseTap()
    }

    @objc func activateSubscription() {
        viewModel.activateSubscription()
    }
}
```

I am trying to add the target action to my `collapsedActivateNowBtn`, but no action is performed on adding this target in `configureSubViews`

The `configure(with viewModel: ReActivateSubscriptionViewPresentable)` method is called after I instantiate the ReActivateSubscriptionView.

Comment: Samarth, I don't totally understand what you mean but I've put in an answer correctly explaining how to subclass UIButton so that it "knows" it has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear.

But here's how you correctly subclass `UIButton` so that it "knows" it has been clicked:

```
import UIKit

class MyButton: UIButton {

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(clicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func clicked() {
        print("I have been clicked")
    }

}
```

(As a rule, **always subclass**. Don't try to add behaviors you need "from above" - subclass.)

Again it's unclear exactly what you're trying to do, OP, but this is how you make a button "know" what is happening.